# Cascading dropdowns In MVC5 On demand load is giving 500 Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I currently have a data model that was generated from an existing database utilizing Entity Framework 6 (ASP.NET MVC 5). I'm currently working with two data tables: Contracts and Employees. They both are related to the Company table, so each table has CompanyID as a foreign key. When I scaffolded the Create Contract view, it currently has drop down lists for EmployeeID and CompanyID. What I'm trying to do is have the user select the CompanyID and only show the Employees that are tied to that Company.

I've tried using jQuery's getJSON method, but it's returning a 500 error due to a circular reference as I'm returning a JSON serialized Employee object which has a reference to Company (causing the circular reference error).

The Employee Model:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Contracts = new HashSet<Contract>();
        this.HoleLoggings = new HashSet<HoleLogging>();
    }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<HoleLogging> HoleLoggings { get; set; }
}
```

The Contracts Model:

```
 public partial class Contract
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Contract()
    {
        this.ContractDetails = new HashSet<ContractDetail>();
        this.Platforms = new HashSet<Platform>();
        this.ShiftReports = new HashSet<ShiftReport>();
    }

    public int ContractID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsApproved { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ContractDetail> ContractDetails { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ShiftReport> ShiftReports { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the ActionMethod in my Contracts Controller:

```
        public JsonResult GetEmployees(int id)
    {

        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        var employeeList = from e in db.Employees 
                           where (e.CompanyID == id) 
                           select e.
        employees.AddRange(employeeList);
        return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

The View's form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Contract</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID, "CompanyID",     htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "EmployeeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select an Employee", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#CompanyID").change(function () {
        $("#EmployeeID").empty();
        var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetEmployees")', { id: $(this).val() }, function (employees) {
            var employeesSelect = $("#EmployeeID");
            $.each(employees, function (i, employee) {
                employeesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: employee.value,
                    text: employee.text
                }));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answers here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678015/entity-framework-4-1-mvc3-jsonresult-and-circular-references

Comment: This was basically the same result as what was listed below, but his code definitely made it easier for me to understand. Thanks for the contribution, nonetheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a collection of anonymous objects containing just the properties you need (no point sending a whole lot of data to the client that you don't even use)

```
employees.AddRange(employeeList);

var data = employees.Select(e => new
{
  value = e.EmployeeID,
  text = e.Name
};
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: This absolutely worked, but the brackets on new[] threw it for a loop. Once I removed those, everything works fine! I appreciate your reply and for being so quick. Question for you: should I have created a ViewModel instead of passing only the values I need, or is this an appropriate/acceptable way to go about this?

Comment: No real need for a view model in this case. Your browser knows nothing about what a c# class is, and the `Json()` method is just going to serialize it to the format understood by the browser anyway - i.e. to `[{ value: 1, text: 'John' }, { value: 2, text: 'Peter' }]`

Comment: And of course you can even skip creating `List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();` and just project the query directly into the anonymous collection